# Topology boundary point terminology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have 2 circles that intersect tangentially, and I'm looking at the set of all points within both circles. For example, the set of all

$(x,y)$ such that $$(x-2)^2+y^2 \le 4$$ or $$(x+3)^2+y^2 \le 9$$

Looking at the boundary of this region, is there a special topological term for the type of boundary point the origin is here (where the boundary crosses itself)?

Comment: Point of tangency?   Not sure what you’re looking for.

Comment: @Randall, is there a topological term for a region that does not contain any boundary points like the origin here?

Comment: I guess it’s not clear to me what makes this different from any other boundary point.

Comment: I think the distinction I'm getting at is whether the boundary is topologically equivalent to a circle or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tangent circles are not homeomorphic to a circle because the former has a cutpoint, the point of tangency, and the latter has none.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I guess the term cutpoint is what I was looking for.